# Adding a library to intelliJ

Tags: java

[image: The error]

I tried to add this plotter.jar library with the module dependency and libraries module structure
and it still doesn't read it.

Comment: Try build it again, invalid caches and restart Intellij. NoClassDefound error is usually whenever it can't be found at run time. I'd recommend you just search for solutions to "NoClassDefFound" instead of focusing in on the library

Comment: What do you mean by "still doesn't read it"? What do you expect "it" to do? What does it do instead? Try to explain the problem with words and don't expect a single screenshot to tell us what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't post images of code please. Copy the text. Anyway, looks like a problem with the classpath. If you scroll to the top of that run dialog at the bottom, IntelliJ will show the run command which was executed. `/path/to/java blah blah`. Post that. If the library isn't on the classpath, you may get exceptions like that

Comment: "I tried to add this plotter.jar library". How? Did you modify pom.xml or used some other way?

Comment: What entries have you added to your `pom.xml`? As you are in a Maven project you should add libraries as Maven dependency.